# What is the lazyUpdate attribute on Http from Angular 5

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

I built an interceptor tho pass my authorization token in the request header. Strangely, as I debug the code, the attribute **headers** which is an Array is empty while the **lazyUpdate** attribute has my token in the Authorization. Why is that? I have spent the last 3 hours of my life trying to figure out why my token does not get into my Spring Boot API

Thanks in advance

Below is my interceptor code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 constructor(public authContext: AuthContextService) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

request = request.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authContext.getEncodedToken()}`
  }
 });

 return next.handle(request);
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but as your question sits now it's impossible to debug. Please post your relevant source code.

Comment: @Phix, it is done ;)

Comment: Did you figure this out? What was the issue?